# python check that a string is compound just from salt chars

Tags: python, regex

I want to check that my received `access_token` is based only on

`SALT_CHARS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'`

what's the best way to check. I checked out `re`, But I don't think it's relevant here.
I can build a function that checks it but interested if there are a one liners that can do that

`is_build_from_salt_chars_only(token) -> returns bool true/false`

examples:

`a8B4` -> `true`

`a8#4` -> `false`

Comment: Hint: look into `set`s and set differences…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on hint from @deceze:

```
def is_build_from_salt_chars_only(token):
    return set(token).issubset(set(SALT_CHARS))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
def is_built_from_salt_chars_only(token):
    return all(char in SALT_CHARS for char in token)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Salt chars are all alphanumeric, the easiest way would be to use `str` function `.isalnum()`:

```
salt = "adeooAEDjifewOfej23923mklEWE"
non_salt = "\dekoS,"

print(salt.isalnum())
# prints True
print(non_salt.isalnum())
# prints False
```

Here are 2 more possiblities:

```
SALT_CHARS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'

salt = "adeooAEDjifewOfej23923mklEWE"
non_salt = "\dekoS,"

# either with sets:
print(set(salt).issubset(set(SALT_CHARS)))
# prints True
print(set(non_salt).issubset(set(SALT_CHARS)))
# prints False

# or with a list comprehension:
print(all([x in SALT_CHARS for x in salt]))
# prints True

print(all([x in SALT_CHARS for x in non_salt]))
# prints False
```

Answer (score 1):

re is definitely a way to carry this out. Try the below:

```
SALT_CHARS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'

def is_build_from_salt_chars_only(token):
    if re.match('^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]+$', token, flags=0):
    return True
else:
    return False

print(is_build_from_salt_chars_only('a8B4'))
print(is_build_from_salt_chars_only('a8#4'))
```

As pointed out below, the SALT_CHARS given mean you can use the much more concise:

```
re.match(r'^\w+$', token, flags=0)
```

Comment: Same as this: re.match(r'^\w+$', token, flags=0)

Comment: Well said - added.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import re
SALT_CHARS = '^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789]*$'

def salt(tested_string):
    return re.match(SALT_CHARS, tested_string) is not None
```

.

```
print(salt('asdf657'))
#returns true
print(salt('asdf6!57'))
#returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be smart and efficient way to do it:

```
salt = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
ascii = [ord(i) for i in a]
ascii.sort()
print(ascii)
[48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122]
```

So a fast way would be something like:

```
for i in 'ab#4':
    if not 48 <= ord(i) < 57 and not 65 <= ord(i) <= 90 and not 97 <= ord(i) <= 122:
        return False
return True
```

Works only if SALT won't change, so you can harcode values to speed up execution time.